# Heatmap for binary data

Tags: r, heatmap

I am trying to make a heatmap of proteomic data from mass spectroscopy form a group of patients regarding the detection of a particular protein in samples. The data has been divided into a 0 (no protein detected) and 1 (protein detected) arrangement. I want to divide the proteins into two clusters (one where I can do skewed discrimination and one for which too few proteins were detected in the samples). Unfortunately, after doing a heatmap, the data doesn't appear to be split 0-1.

I entered sample data for patients and proteins. They were originally in a csv file, so they are here in the form of data.frame. As the heatmap requires matrix data, I changed it. Next, I create the heat map. However, it is multicolored, which doesn't make much sense.

|  | Patient_1 | Patient_2 | Patient_3 | Patient_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Protein_1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Protein_2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Protein_3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Protein_4 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Protein_5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Protein_6 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Protein_7 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Protein_8 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

```
data = data.frame (a = c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1),
                b = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1),
                c = c(0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0),
                d = c(1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1))
data
data_matrix = as.matrix(data)
data_matrix
data_numeric = matrix (as.numeric(data_matrix), ncol= 4, nrow= 8)
row.names(data_numeric) = c("Protein_1", "Protein_2", "Protein_3", "Protein_4","Protein_5","Protein_6","Protein_7","Protein_8")
colnames(data_numeric) = c("Patient_1","Patient_2","Patient_3","Patient_4")
data_numeric
```

[image]

```
heatmap(data_numeric)
```

[image]
Would anyone like to help me correct the mistake I'm making and split the heatmap into two clusters?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want the matrix to be scaled by `heatmap()`.

```
heatmap(data_numeric, scale='none', col=c('#CCCCCC', '#FF4444'), margins=c(8, 6))
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(data_numeric)
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), dim = c(8L, 4L), dimnames = list(
    c("Protein_1", "Protein_2", "Protein_3", "Protein_4", "Protein_5", 
    "Protein_6", "Protein_7", "Protein_8"), c("Patient_1", "Patient_2", 
    "Patient_3", "Patient_4")))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I divide the dendrogram on the left into two branches?